# Looking for manga or manhwa where the main character can change into different characters from the game

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Manga or Manhwa where he can change into different characters from the game. I can remember that he usually uses the black-haired old man with cigarettes and there was this one time he changed into a martial artist character with white clothes. I forgot the plot but it's fantasy and all I can remember is the characters since that was long ago.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: One of these, perhaps; https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/trapped-in-a-video-game

Comment: was it colored or not ? any other memorable characters ?
can you describe the black-haired old man, like clothes or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

It might be ***[Maou-sama, Retry!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/tp3tyaa/maou-sama-retry)***...

> What do you do when the MMO you’ve run for 15 years comes to an end? Akira Ono didn’t get much of a choice — he woke up trapped inside the world of his own game in the body of his in-game character: the Demon Lord. With an outcast child as his sidekick, he tries his best to survive the cruel fantasy world of his own creation, prosecution from the good guys, and of course, the final boss.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which this matches the manga/manhwa described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't.

Comment: Can he change into different characters?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I believe he can transform into this character [link](https://demon-lord-retry.fandom.com/wiki/Zero_Kirisame)

Comment: Ah, yeah, also referenced in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/DemonLordRetry (TV Tropes).